# How pass value from one component to another(without @Input)

Tags: angular

I have main page with the several buttons, which are located in separate components and don't have communication as parent-child, but they have to navigate to the one page. 
I should pass value from the span to new page and set it to input value, if it is empty. How can I do this?

```
    public sendForm(): void {
        this.navigationService.navigateToNewCustomerPage();
}


<div class="slider-info">
                <p class="amount-title slider-info-text">How much do you need<span class="slider-question">?</span></p>
                <p class="slider-info-text"><span class="amount">{{amount|currency:'USD': 'symbol-narrow': '1.0'}}</span></p>
            </div>
            <mat-slider class="slider"
                                    [disabled]="sliderSettings.disabled"
                                    [invert]="sliderSettings.invert"
                                    [max]="sliderSettings.max"
                                    [min]="sliderSettings.min"
                                    [step]="sliderSettings.step"
                                    [thumbLabel]="sliderSettings.thumbLabel"
                                    [tickInterval]="sliderSettings.tickInterval"
                                    [(ngModel)]="sliderSettings.value"
                                    color="primary"
                                    (input)="onInputChange($event)">
            </mat-slider>
            <span class="slider-value slider-value-min">{{sliderSettings.min|currency:'USD': 'symbol-narrow': '1.0'}}</span>
            <span class="slider-value slider-value-max">{{sliderSettings.max|currency:'USD': 'symbol-narrow': '1.0'}}</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can use `services` and `EventEmitter` inside the service

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern where you have a service class: this contains a value you want to be emitted as an observable and a method that allows the observable value to be updated.

The child calls the `communicateUpdate` method to update the value.

The parent (and whatever other component is interested) subscribes to the observable.

Here is a rough sample.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyDummyService {
    constructor() {
    }
    private TheValueIWantMyParentToSee  = new Subject<any>();
    ObservableValue$ = this.TheValueIWantMyParentToSee.asObservable();

    communicateUpdatedValue(newValue:any){
        this.TheValueIWantMyParentToSee.next(newValue);
    }

}
```

The Child component calls communicateUpdatedValue to publish a value, anything that is subscribed will get the updated value. if nothing is subscribed it just disappears

```
export class TheParentWhoSubscribes{
  childValue: any;
  constructor(private myDummyService: MyDummyService ) {
    myDummyService.ObservableValue$.subscribe(response => {
      this.childValue= response
    });
  }
}
```

Here your parent class subscribes to the observable. whenever a value is updated by the child component `this.childValue` is set to the new value

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe from the observable in ngOnDestroy or the subscription could remain for longer than intended.

Comment: @Kevin, tell me please, why do you inject private httpRequesthandler: HttpRequestHandler in MyDummeService? You don't use it

Comment: And  I try to use communicateUpdatedValue method, I get value in component, that has value, but in component, that should get value using myDummyService.ObservableValue$, value is not appear.

Comment: @prolina Hi, I used a snippet of code that I wrote for a production app and forgot to remove the httpRequestHandler I was using. You do not need it. Are you subscribing to it in the constructor like so `myDummyService.ObservableValue$.subscribe(response => {
      this.childValue= response
    });`

Comment: @Kevin, 
 `
 constructor(
  private readonly passAmountValueService: PassAmountValueService,
 ) {
  super();
  this.passAmountValueService.ObservableValue$.subscribe(res => {
  this.amount = res;
  console.log(this.amount);
  });
  this.buildFormGroup();
 }
`

Comment: and console.log(this.amount) is not performed